# Is there a simple way to make text solid and background transparent

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve the effect of having my text solid, nothing shows through, but the background color of the element holding the text, to be with opacity (o.5 for example).
I am currently do it with one element on top of the other.
Am wondering if there is a way to do it with only one element.

```
<div class="body">
   here be a background image

   <div class="title"> TITLE WITH FAINT WHITE BACKGROUND</div>
</div>
```

Comment: bg to body or title? show the css what you're trying...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`rgba`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba%28%29) to define the color which supports alpha.

```
.title{
    color:black;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

Support for this feature: http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba

---

Full sample

```css
.body{
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  background:url('http://lorempixel.com/500/200/abstract/1');
}
.title{
   color:black;
   background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 }
```

```html
<div class="body">
   <div class="title">TITLE WITH FAINT WHITE BACKGROUND</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @BhojendraNepal i am assuming from the question "***the background color of the element holding the text, to be with opacity***" that the OP wants a solid color. The sample code posted by the OP i think is the final code he wants.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this in a single element, you need to set the rgba color as the first image, so that it will be rendered above.

And this makes impossible to set it as color, you need an image.

The 2 posibilities to achieve this are image() and linear-gradient:

```css
.test {
    background-image: image(rgba(0,0,255,.5)), url("http://placekitten.com/800/600");
}

.test {
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,.5), rgba(255,255,255,.5)), url("http://placekitten.com/1000/800");
  
}
```

```html
<div class="test">TEST</div>
```

However, the first one is valid CSS as the spec, but as far as I know it is not supported by any browser

[w3c reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-images-20120417/#color-images)